# GEE Using a Bernolli Model and Log link

Tags: binary-data, percentage, generalized-estimating-equations

Conceptually I am interested in a pretty simple question: Do screening rates (dichotomous outcome) differ between an intervention and control group. We have a number of clinics that patients are drawn from so I ran a GEE to account for this. We are really interested in percentage differences between the two groups when we account for clinic size. For the GEE I used a Bernoulli (Type of Model) and the log link function. This obviously returns a regression coefficient. How do I transform this regression coefficient to a percentage difference? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using a log link with a Bernoulli model instead of the logit link?

Comment: It's my understanding that the logit link will give me Odds Ratios. The folks that I am working with what percentage differences from the GEE, and the log was suggested as a way to get there. If you have a way to get me to percentage differences (not in terms of ORs), I'm all ears. Thank you!

Comment: You can convert odds ratios to probabilities easily enough.  The problem with a log link is... what do you do when your resultant "probability" $>1$?

Comment: Great, would you mind walking me through this. I reran the GEE with the logit link and I get an OR of .57 for my intervention/control group predictor. How do I convert this to the percentage differences between these two groups for the actual outcome (screening rates). I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211176/converting-logistic-regression-coefficient-and-confidence-interval-from-log-odds should help

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I have had a few days to reflect on this and run some more models. I hope that you will indulge me further. When I convert my OR from above (.57) into a probability/percentage I get, roughly, a 30% difference between my two groups. However, when I look at basic percentages at the individual and clinic level the difference between the two groups ranges from 3-5%. Why the drastic difference? Is the percentage difference from the GEE with a logit link the percentage difference in Odds?